# Retrofit OkHttp SSLHandshakeException

Tags: android, ssl, https, retrofit, okhttp

I am using OkHttp as the client in Retrofit.  I am unable to hit a certain https url.  This server supports TLS 1.0 only and the following ciphers
**TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5**

Here's how I am instantiating my OkHttpClient:

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        }};

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        client.setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

        client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }


    return client;
}
```

And my app keeps throwing this exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x9742f000: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:770 0xab9fcc4d:0x00000000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OkHttp no longer supports RC4 in its default config since OkHttp v2.3 ([release notes](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/dedcb5dc596ce108afd7b374bbeba270d9efe77c/CHANGELOG.md#version-230)). You can use the `ConnectionSpec` ([javadoc](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/ConnectionSpec.html)) to enable it, the `ConnectionSpecTest.java` ([source code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.5.0/okhttp-tests/src/test/java/com/squareup/okhttp/ConnectionSpecTest.java)) shows some examples.

Comment: The `supportsTlsExtensions(true)` was key.  You saved me a lot of time, thanks!

Comment: Thank you supportsTlsExtensions(true) fixed it