# SSLHandshakeException in Android 4.4.4 Samsung Tab E SM-T561

Tags: java, android, retrofit, sslhandshakeexception

Everything works fine in Android version 9 (Mobile phone), but while running on "Samsung Galaxy Tab E SM-T561" android version "4.4.4" it shows error

"**Javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error**".

I am using Retrofit2 library

Code I have used.

```
public static Retrofit getApiClient()
{
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    if (retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: Can you post your url when you're getting that error. Is it begins with `http` or `https`?

Comment: begins with https.

Comment: This [SSLProtocolException with HTTPs on Retrofit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417400/sslprotocolexception-with-https-on-retrofit2) might help you.

Comment: I've fixed the issue, using other some code